# subsequences of a sequence converging to elements of a countable and uncountable set

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Firstly, I want to show that if {x(k) : k belongs to N} is a countable subset of R then there is a sequence (an) such that for every k in N there is a subsequence of (an) converging to x(k).

I have thought of the example (an) = x(k-1) where k is the smallest prime factor of n. Do I need to show anything else or I have proved it?

Secondly, I can't think of an example of a sequence that has subsequences converging to every real number. What examples are there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Give an example of a sequence of real numbers with subsequences converging to every real number](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256840/give-an-example-of-a-sequence-of-real-numbers-with-subsequences-converging-to-ev) (sorry, should have checked for duplicates before I posted an answer)

Comment: Actually, it's only the second question that's a duplicate. But the answer to the first question is, yes, nice proof.

Comment: Start with $-1$, $1$. Then list the multiples of $1/2$ from $-2$ to $2$. Then list the multiples of $1/3$ from $-3$ to $3$...

Answer (score 2):

Let $S$ be an enumeration of a countable dense set, e.g., of the rationals. Then $$s_1,s_2,s_1,s_2,s_3,s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4,s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4,s_5,\dots$$ will have a subsequence converging to every real.